# Independent "Submit" button for tabbed form in Create

Tags: admin-on-rest

I already made 2 types of create page:

1. Create single record.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19276305/29556148-823e44ec-8757-11e7-82bd-c008d227e26b.png]

2. Import multiple records from xlsx file.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19276305/29556152-86035eaa-8757-11e7-9301-427ad71fcd18.png]

Now I want to implement 2 independent buttons:

1. Save
2. Import

meaning that when I click on button 1, only button 1 works.

Here is my code:

```
<Create {...this.props}>
            <TabbedForm toolbar="">
                <FormTab label="Single record">
                    <ReferenceInput label="Centre" source="centre" reference="centre" sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }} allowEmpty>
                        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
                    </ReferenceInput>
                    <TextInput source="fullname" />
                    <TextInput source="serial   " />
                    <TextInput source="birthday" />
                    <TextInput source="join_date" />
                    <TextInput source="remark" />
                    <SaveButton label="Save" redirect="show" submitOnEnter={true} />
                </FormTab>
                <FormTab label="Import from xlsx">
                    <ReferenceInput label="Centre" source="centre_import" reference="centre" sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }} allowEmpty>
                        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
                    </ReferenceInput>
                    <label id="customLabel">
                        <input id="upload" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} type="file" hidden
                               onClick={(event)=> {
                                   event.target.value = null;
                               }}
                               onChange={
                                   (event) => {
                                       this.fileName.textContent = event.target.files[0].name;
                                   }
                               }
                        />
                        <FlatButton primary label="Select file" icon={<ActionFile />} onClick={() => {
                            this.textInput.click();
                        }}/>
                        <span id="fileName" ref={(span) => { this.fileName = span; }}></span>
                    </label>
                    <SaveButton label="Import" redirect={false} submitOnEnter={true} />
                </FormTab>
            </TabbedForm>
        </Create>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code, others will be more likely to help you in this case :)

Comment: What exactly didn't you manage to achieve ? I see you have your custom button already.

Comment: @filaton: I already updated my code. Thank you!

Comment: @Gildas Please check my code. My <SaveButton> is not correct ^^

Comment: What isn't correct about it ?

Comment: @Gildas The buttons do not link with the Form. When I click on the button, nothing happen. Do you have any suggestions for it? As I read on the Admin-on-rest documentation,  we should use <Toolbar> instead of using <SaveButton> directly.

Comment: Ah I see, you want that only one button is displayed at a time, depending on the selected tab ? Is that right ?

Comment: In addition to make it actually work of course :) Please confirm so that I can write a thorough answer ^^

Comment: @Gildas Correct ^^, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to keep a single button here. You may add a text inside the importation tab explaining that clicking on save will import the file.

However, you still have to deal with the redirection. To do so, you'll have to implement a custom `SaveButton`:

1. Copy the code of the default [SaveButton](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/button/SaveButton.js) into a `SaveOrImportButton` file.
2. Update its `mapStateToProps` function and use redux-form [`getFormValues` selector](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/Selectors.md/#-code-getformvalues-formname-string-code-returns-code-state-gt-formvalues-object-code-) to inspect the form values and determine whether its an importation.
3. Use this knowledge to customize the button:

   - You may update the label to `Import` if the user selected a file. The label will update immediately after the file field gets dirty.
   - You can change the redirect value at [L22](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/button/SaveButton.js#L22).

Use this button inside a `Toolbar` component and pass this component to the `toolbar` prop of the `Create` component.